# return promise from function which using fetch

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, nativescript, es6-promise, fetch-api

My problem is I'm calling refresh token function with interval every x seconds, I have hardcoded navigation to the homepage in refreshToken function
and **can't clear interval** in the function when doing navigate because the interval is declared in another file.

What I want is call refreshToken from other file and return promise
need to navigate the user to the homepage or not(navigate to the homepage if response access token or refresh token is null), if yes clear interval and navigate after this.

here is refreshToken function which is in methods.js:

```
let refreshToken=(url,refresh_token)=>{

console.log("access_token check");
let currentMin=getMinute();

if(currentMin===0){
    currentMin=60;
}
if(appSettings.getNumber("tkTime") > currentMin){
    currentMin=currentMin+60;
}

if(currentMin - appSettings.getNumber("tkTime") >= 4){

    fetch(url,{
        headers: new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization':`Bearer ${refresh_token}`
          }),
        method:'POST'
    }).then((res) => {


        return res.json();          
    }).then((data)=>{
        if(data.refresh_token !== null || data.access_token !== null){

            appSettings.setString("refresh_token",data.refresh_token);
            appSettings.setString("access_token",data.access_token);
            appSettings.setNumber("tkTime",getMinute());  
            console.log("token refreshed");
        }
        else{
            topmost().navigate({moduleName:"Home/home",clearHistory: true});
        }

    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);

    });
}    

}
```

and here is code part when i'm calling this function from userPage.js:

```
 const myModules = require('~/methods.js');
 myModules.refreshToken(myModules.refUrl,appSettings.getString("access_token"),appSettings.getString("refresh_token"));

ref=timer.setInterval(() => {
    myModules.refreshToken(myModules.refUrl,appSettings.getString("access_token"),appSettings.getString("refresh_token"));
},1000*30);
```

Comment: Return the promise from the function, and do the `.then(data => { if (!data.token) { clearInterval(); navigate(); } }).catch(console.error)` part in the other module.

Comment: @Bergi my question was how to return the promise from function in this case, i know hot to use then

Comment: Just put a `return` in front of your promise chain?

Answer (score 0):

Return fetch from function and write handle else condition also otherwise it'll break.

```
let refreshToken = (url, refresh_token) => {
    console.log("access_token check");
    let currentMin = getMinute();
    if (currentMin === 0) {
        currentMin = 60;
    }
    if (appSettings.getNumber("tkTime") > currentMin) {
        currentMin = currentMin + 60;
    }
    if (currentMin - appSettings.getNumber("tkTime") >= 4) {
        return fetch(url, {
            headers: new Headers({
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': `Bearer ${refresh_token}`
            }),
            method: 'POST'
        }).then((res) => {
            return res.json();
        }).then((data) => {
            if (data.refresh_token !== null || data.access_token !== null) {
                appSettings.setString("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
                appSettings.setString("access_token", data.access_token);
                appSettings.setNumber("tkTime", getMinute());
                console.log("token refreshed");
            } else {
                topmost().navigate({
                    moduleName: "Home/home",
                    clearHistory: true
                });
            }
        })
    } else {
        // .then will throw an error if not write
        return new Promise(resolve => resolve( /*Some Data*/ ));
    }
}
```